# WordPress generate_rewrite_rules without specific slug

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

**Goal :** I need to generate custom URL on WordPress to convert the slug into variable. Anything after slash will be considered as fruit's name.

For example, to produce banana, I need to go to
**website.com/u/banana**

What I expected : **website.com/banana**

**Problem :** I need to remove that **'/u/'** part from the URL and prevent any possible conflict with other standard pages slug.

**My code :**

```
add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', function ( $wp_rewrite ){
    $wp_rewrite->rules = array_merge(
        ['u/([^/]*)' => 'index.php?fruit=$matches[1]'],
        $wp_rewrite->rules
    );
} );

add_filter( 'query_vars', function( $query_vars ){ 
    $query_vars[] = 'fruit';
    return $query_vars;
} );

add_filter( 'home_template', 'wpa3396_page_template' );
function wpa3396_page_template( $page_template )
{
    if ( get_query_var( 'fruit' ) ) :
      $page_template = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'templates/fruitcase.php';
      return $page_template;
    endif;
}
```

Comment: There's a fundamentally hard problem hidden in this requirement "... and prevent any possible conflict with other standard pages slug". There are three ways to do that: list all the fruits; list every URL that's _not_ a fruit; come up with some pattern that matches all fruits and nothing else. The broader you make the pattern, the more likely it will catch some other page, which is why having a set prefix is so common.

Comment: Yes, that's make sense. It's not easy to achieve. I found an idea to just add special character on that, similar to what they do on Medium. So instead of **website.com/banana** - I change it to **website.com/@banana**. Do you think there is a downside for using this kind of solution?